# Create a new site with a recent version or use the old one

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

The project I'm working on is based on Django 1.4 and I can't change / update it actually.

I have to work on an API to modify data on that site.

I thought I would use Django Rest Framework to do it.

Would there be a problem if I start a new site from scratch using Django 3.X and the newest version of the DRF, using the same DataBase as the oldest site ?

I mean, if by using the API on the new site I change data on the DataBase, this is also going to be changed on the "old" ?

On the other side, I could keep working on the "old" site and use an old version of DRF but those version are less complete, less documented and less secure.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "change data in the db"? Just having your new app access the existing db and change the data? Or also modify the tables by changing the models? btw, don't use Django 3.x, it's not released yet and I would always go for a LTS release for production code. Latest LTS is 2.2.

Comment: I just mean acess the existing database and change the data ( add some rows when adding a client for exemple ) but not modifying the models. Thanks for the information about Django's version

Comment: This could be the start of a migration project, so yes, I would start a new project on django 2.2 and DRF 3, make the models with `managed = False`, accessing the same db as the 'old' project to modify the data. At some stage, it would be quite easy to migrate the rest of the website to the new project, once your API can handle all the operations required by the website.

Comment: In that case I have to create the same models as the one in the old website but just add a managed = False in the meta Class ?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Alright thanks for these answers

Comment: Well to be precise: you need models that use the same database columns with the same field type. But if you see bad naming conventions etc... you could even change the names of the models and fields (and specify the corresponding table name and column name).

Comment: Ok, thanks again, if you sum it up in the answer below I'll be able to close the question

Comment: Another question, what if I have to create new tables in the DataBase for the new site ? Would this be a problem ?

Comment: New tables aren’t going to affect your old app. No problem. Only if you modify tables do you have to tread with care. Adding columns won’t be a problem but modifying existing columns of course will require changes to the old app.

Comment: What do you mean as modifying existing columns ? Changing Data Types / conditions (Maximal length of a string for exemple ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a great opportunity to kick-start a migration project to a supported and secure version of Django. Always use an LTS version: 2.2 is the most recent LTS version, 3.x isn't released yet.

You will need to copy the models from the old app and set `managed = False`, access the same db as the old project to modify the data with the new API.

Once your API can handle all the functionalities required by the website, it'll be quite easy to migrate the entire website.

Note the following:

- Your models in the new project need to use the same database tables and columns, with the same field type. But nothing precludes you from renaming the actual models and fields (if you feel the old project used "bad" naming conventions), as long as you then specify `db_column` (on the field) and `db_table` (on the model) to let Django know the mapping to the existing database.
- You can add new models and tables to your existing database (with `managed = True`) without affecting your old app.

If at some stage you need to modify existing tables:

- You might then consider switching to `managed = True` (and change your old app to `managed = False`), making sure that prior to that you'd have cleared the migrations table from the database and then run the migrations with `fake` set (so as to not actually migrate anything). I would do that if the old app is not maintained anymore.
- If the old app is still maintained it's a bit more tricky. You would probably have to make the db changes directly in SQL.
- Changes that won't affect the old app: Adding new columns.
- Changes that will affect the old app: Anything that restricts constraints, or adds constraints, or changes the data type.
- Changes that might affect the old app: Loosening constraints. This won't affect the existing data in your db, but it might trip validators of the old app that expect data in a certain format and get "invalid" data for the new data.

Comment: Well, thanks for this post that gave me every information I needed